# Node server for electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm creating an aplication with Electron + React. The app has to allow users to save files on the server (something like Google Drive).
Now, im building the server side with express but i dont now how to send files to the client. How could i do it?
Would it be nice to use an FTP server instead of node?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. In addition, do not ask for opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are 2 options regardless:

1) You just send your app unique link of the file witch expires after some time.

2) You stream the file to electron directly(Just google `node streaming`.

Thats about it.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
    ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
    ...solicit opinions rather than facts." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer